# Webchat for LAMP server with moderation & other features

Tags: gratis, web-apps, chat, lamp

Need to find a web chat application, preferably free one that can be integrated with a standard LAMP server, with certain features:

- there have to be chat rooms;
- there have to be moderators/admins;
- moderators/admins should be able to change users' avatars;
- users should not be able to change their avatars;
- moderators/admins should have an invisible mode (optional).

Could you name one with desired functionality?